# MySQL Locking Tables with millions of rows

Tags: mysql

I've been running a website, with a large amount of data in the process.

A user's save data like ip , id , date to the server and it is stored in a MySQL database. Each entry is stored as a single row in a table.

Right now there are approximately 24 million rows in the table

**Problem 1:**

Things are getting slow now, as a full table scan can take too many  minutes but I already indexed the table.

**Problem 2:**

If a user is pulling a select data from table it could potentially block all other users (as the table is locked) access to the site until the query is complete.

**Our server**

- 32 Gb Ram
- 12 core with 24 thread cpu
- table use MyISAM engine
  [image]

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(impresn), SUM(rae), SUM(reve), `date` FROM `publisher_ads_hits` WHERE date between '2015-05-01' AND '2016-04-02' AND userid='168' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: The table is not blocked on SELECTs. On updates/inserts maybe. And indexes are used depending on the queries you execute. Don't just throw in indexes.

Comment: Provide table structure with indexes and queries.Try to change engine to innodb.

Comment: Run `explain select ...` to see what indexes are used

Comment: check above i add it explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to explain, query doesn't use index. Try to add composite index (userid, date).
If you have many update and delete operations, try to change engine to INNODB.

Answer (score 2):

Lock to comment from @Max P. If you write to MyIsam Tables ALL SELECTs are blocked. There is only a Table lock. If you use InnoDB there is a ROW Lock that only locks the ROWs they need. Aslo show us the EXPLAIN of your Queries. So it is possible that you must create some new one. MySQL can only handle one Index per Query. So if you use more fields in the Where Condition it can be useful to have a COMPOSITE INDEX over this fields

Comment: thanks for reply i already use where condition in select query , problem is its lock the all site mean html pages also when anyone get data from mysql

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem is full table scan. Some suggestion are:

- Partition the table based on date and dont keep more than 6-12months data in live system
- Add an index on user_id